# save data to database with click of button/link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am making a simple jQuery mobile app, where one of the pages is about a restaurant. 
On that page, I want to have a button that, when clicked, saves the information of the restaurant to a database.

I already have a php code that can save data to my database, and i have this javascript code that works together with it.
Though this is used for saving data from a google maps `infowindow` when closed. I just need a on click button.

```
var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address + "&description=" + description + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
downloadUrl(url, function (data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
        infowindow.close();
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
}
```

What is the easiest approach to this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Is it possible to do like this, if i create a button with id #btn_save :

> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $(document).on("click","#btn_save",function() {
>   "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + john + "&address=" + lolstreet 12 +
>   "&description=" + this is restaurant john + "&lat=" + xx.xx() +
>   "&lng=" + yy.yy();
>
> }); });

Sorry, i know i should be learning the basics first.. :/

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you need to add button onClick event handler? If so, here you go (using jquery 1.9+):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //onClick event handler for button with id "btn_save"
  $(document).on("click","#btn_save",function() {
    //Your code here
  });
});
```

Comment: "i'm making a simple jquery mobile app" he is using jQuery.

Comment: @Shawn31313 I don't see how it was my fault, but sure I will add it.

Comment: @Shawn31313 yep, he did :)